# How to input these symbols in LaTeX?

Tags: symbols

[image]

How can I type the underlined symbols in LaTeX? I cannot recognize what letters they are.

Comment: `\mathscr{S}`and `\mathscr{T}` according to http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: Requiring the `mathrsfs` package.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character)